# Mysql queries error

Tags: c++, mysql

**Code:**

```
MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
MYSQL_RES* result;
MYSQL_ROW row;

void student_login(string enrollno,string passwd)
{

    if(mysql_query(con,"SELECT * FROM user_student WHERE ENROLLMENTNO='enrollno' "))  
    {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    result=mysql_store_result(con);
    if(result==NULL)
        finish_with_error(con);

    int num_fields=mysql_num_fields(result);

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) 
        { 
            printf("%s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL"); 
        } 

        printf("\n"); 
    }

    cout<<" i m done";
}
```

**Database:**

```
`enrollmentno     password`
```

I am getting error of access violation. When I debugged using breakpoints the problem seemed to be in mysql_fetch_row function.

Comment: This can't be complete; where is `result` declared?

Comment: i've edited the post.plz check now...

Answer (score 0):

You have used `row=mysql_fetch_row(result);` twice.

Remove this line `row=mysql_fetch_row(result);`

Comment: thanx...but that did'nt help...my while loop is not being executed.